# Calculate currency from variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created two number sliders with jQuery UI which output a calculation to `#total`.

From the value generated in `#total`, I am trying to generate two currency conversions using [money.js](http://josscrowcroft.github.io/money.js/) openexchangerates.com's api. These are appended to `ul.currencies`.

The exchange values are outputting fine when the page loads. However, when the value of `#total` is altered using the sliders, the change is not reflected by the two generated exchange values.

How can I enable the exchange values in `ul.currencies` to update when the value in `#total` is updated?

Here is my calculation code:

```
$("#total").val("0");
$("#amount").val("Amount A");
$("#amountb").val("Amount B");

$( function() {

    var p = {
        0: "zero",
        1: "one hundred",
    };
    var t = {
        0: "0",
        1: "100",
    }

    var b = {
        0: "zero",
        1: "one hundred",
    };
    var d = {
        0: "0",
        1: "100",
    }

    $("#slider").slider({

        value: "0",
        min: 0,
        max: 1,
        step: 1,
        slide: function(event, ui) {

            $("#price").val(t[ui.value]);
            $("#amount").val(p[ui.value]);
            var aaa = $("#price").val();
            var bbb = $("#priceb").val();
            $("#total").val(+1500 + +aaa + +bbb);
        }
    });

    $("#sliderb").slider({
        value: "0",
        min: 0,
        max: 1,
        step: 1,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#priceb").val(d[ui.value]);
            $("#amountb").val(b[ui.value]);
            var aaa = $("#price").val();
            var bbb = $("#priceb").val();
            $("#total").val(+1500 + +aaa + +bbb);
        }
    });

    $("#price").val('$' + $("#slider").slider("value"));
    $("#priceb").val('$' + $("#slider").slider("value"));


    // individual base values
    $("#price").val("0");
    $("#priceb").val("0");
```

And here is my exchange rate code:

```
fx.base = "GBP";
fx.settings = {from : "GBP"};

var amount = $("#total").val();



 $.getJSON(
      'http://openexchangerates.org//api/latest.json?app_id=my_key',
      function(data) {
          // Check money.js has finished loading:
          if ( typeof fx !== "undefined" && fx.rates ) {
              fx.rates = data.rates;
              fx.base = data.base;
          } else {
              // If not, apply to fxSetup global:
              var fxSetup = {
                  rates : data.rates,
                  base : data.base
              }
          }

         // now that we have exchange rates, add a few to our page
         var USD = fx.convert(amount, {to: "USD"}); //13.22784197768393
         var EUR = fx.convert(amount, {to: "EUR"}); //8.567532636985659
         var JPY = fx.convert(amount, {to: "JPY"}); //1028.1670562349989

         $("ul.currencies").append("<li>Base value" + amount + "</li>");
         $("ul.currencies").append("<li>EUR estimate: " + EUR + "</li>");
         $("ul.currencies").append("<li>JPY estimate: " + JPY + "</li>");
      }
  );
```

Comment: Which elements are supposed to show the two different currencies?

Comment: A fiddle might put things into better perspective.

Comment: The currencies are supposed to be appended to `ul.currencies` - the value comes from var `amount`.